# Custom View and Placing ImageViews

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have created a custom "View" class and in the class I have overridden the onDraw method so I can draw my game board. Now I need draw my pieces which need to be ImageView's so I can do animations and such. I am not sure though how to draw my images to a specific location on my custom view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my concept was all wrong. I can't add ImageView's to a custom class that extends View. What I ended up having to do is add my custom view to a RelativeLayout, and than add each of my ImageViews to that same layout, and a long as the custom view is added first my imageviews are on top.